# Backup email+attachment and keep proof that they were not not altered

Tags: email, gmail

Say I want to download an email with an attachment (e.g. from Gmail) to back it up on a drive, and delete forever from the mail program (mailbox/archive/trash etc.)

To back up the usual way I can download the print/pdf of an email and download the attachment separately. But how can I have a proof that this email/attachment were not altered by me or anyone else, that they are exactly the ones sent from specific server / sender / on a given time and never altered?

Comment: It's almost impossible to prove a negative. Were you to take both sources as evidence to a lawyer, they may attest that, at that time, both were equivalent, but they couldn't attest to anything that may have been changed before they saw it.

Comment: The way (which has some caveats) to prove that a file hasn‘t been tampered with is to create a hash of that file and publish the hash in a public place (even Twitter would do) or give it to a trusted party. But, as Tetsujin already said, you can‘t prove that the file hasn‘t been changed before. You can‘t even proove that the mail you received is the same mail as the one which was sent (unless the mail was signed).

Comment: thank you, though for my perception this is quite crazy ifor the times we live in :) also the fact that in a service like Google Drive one cannot move an email to Google Drive folder structure, to just keep it in a single place. I am a freak of everything storing everything in a single place though, probably most people would not care. maybe an outlook .msg file could be something close to this use case.

Comment: It's not crazy, you just have to start with a secured communication channel, which Gmail is not.  If the email had originally been sent with GPG, then you could prove it had not been altered, as @nohillside points out.  Aftrer the fact, you can't prove anything.